# How to create a Power Bi measure to calculate First Pass Yield based off unique serial numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a power bi measure that calculates First Pass Yield (FPY) based on unique serial numbers.

```
Measure (FPY) = 
(Count of unique serial numbers that dont have a "Fail" result) 
divided by 
(Count of total amount of unique serial numbers)
```

This measure could then be plotted on a chart that could be dynamically filtered by a date range slicer:

[image]

Comment: So did it work? Lol

Comment: Yes, both methods worked. This is much appreciated....thanks

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
FPY =
VAR FailedSerialNumbers =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Serial Number] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table'), 'Table'[RESULT] = "FAIL" )
    )
VAR SerialNumbers =
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Serial Number] )
VAR FPYResult =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Serial Number] ),
        'Table'[Serial Number] IN EXCEPT ( SerialNumbers, FailedSerialNumbers )
    )
VAR SerialNumberVolume =
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Serial Number] ) )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( FPYResult, SerialNumberVolume )
```

Which yields the following:

[image]

This solution uses two table variables, 1 with your failed serial numbers and another with all serial numbers. Using these tables, I can extract all serial numbers that have never failed using the `EXCEPT` function. Once this value has been calculated we just divide it by the total volume.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method:

```
First Pass Yield = 
VAR distinctCountTotal =
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Serial Number] )
VAR distinctCountFail =
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Serial Number] ), 'Table'[Result] = "Fail" )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( distinctCountTotal - distinctCountFail, distinctCountTotal )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. This worked exactly as I hope. 
Very much appreciated.